# Linux less behavior and stderr

Tags: less, stderr

I'm watching the output of my complicated command with `less`, problem is the `stderr` gets lost. `stderr` lines normally get listed inbetween `stdout` lines inside `less`. I would like them to be printed to the console, and when I exit `less`, to see them there together.

I realize there might be no solution to this, I read about `tee` and `multitee` but no luck so far.

Comment: You're telling me how to redirect stderr to stdout but that's not what I wanted. I don't want stderr to mix with stdout inside less. I would like stderr to be in the terminal when I exit less.

Comment: If `stderr` is redirected to `stdout`, all output to `stderr` _will_ be mixed with the normal output on `stdout`. Piping that output to `less` will show both.

Comment: If I ignore "stderr to be in the terminal when I exit less", I suggest to press Ctrl-L in `less` to repaint the screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe

```
command 2> command.err | less; cat command.err; rm command.err
```

---

Addendum

Here follows a clarification for folk who neglect to *carefully* read the question and who didn't read the OP's clarifying comment above.

haelix pointed out:

> **stderr lines normally get listed inbetween stdout lines inside less**

and, in a comment for early answerers, wrote:

> **You're telling me how to redirect stderr to stdout but that's not what I wanted. I don't want stderr to mix with stdout inside less. I would like stderr to be in the terminal when I exit less**

The problem is probably platform specific, it is certainly something I have experienced on older Unix SVR4 platforms.

If, on such platforms, you do something like

```
 find / ... | less
```

any error messages (e.g. directory permissions) appear like this in less

```
 stdout line 1
 stdout line 2
 error message text
 stdout line 4
```

so that output lines are obscured by error messages.

If you refresh the page the output lines are shown correctly but you lose the error messages. When you exit less the screen is cleared except for a command prompt.

If you do something like

```
  find / ... 2>&1 | less
```

The error messages are intermingled with the standard output. Again when you exit less, the screen is empty.

If you want to first peruse only the standard output in less, then see the error messages after exiting less, you need a different solution.

That is what I was tentatively suggesting in my original, two-line answer.

Comment: @VanillaFace: I have added some clarifying material to my answer.

Comment: @VanillaFace: No, RedGrittyBrick answers exactly to the question asked, as opposite to most other answers which address a different question. His answer was useful at least to me (I found it when I experienced exactly the same problem as OP and wanted stderr to persist after exiting less, which was not the case in Ubuntu by default).

Answer (score 26):

You have to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
$ ./somecommad 2>&1 | less
```

Check the manual for you shell (e.g. [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).)

Comment: Comment for new readers of this old question (not for Joachim particularly) This is what everyone thinks at first scan of the question. But the problem is more subtle - see discussion in comments after [dmckee's answer](http://superuser.com/a/366615/52492)

Comment: The shorthand for **2>&1** is **|&**. Thus, it can be simplified as `$ ./somecommad |& less`

Comment: In Fish, it's the other way around: `./somecommad &| less`

Answer (score 2):

just tell the shell to redirect fd 2 to fd 1 (stderr to stdout)

```
 make 2>&1 | less
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that was lacking from all the answers so far is the reason, why this is happening. The problem here is some kind of race-condition between the process outputting stuff to `stderr` and `less` displaying output from `stdout` on the terminal. If `less` starts displaying *after* all output to `stderr` has been printed to the terminal, then `less` will preserve that and you can see the messages after exiting `less`. OTOH if `less` has already started displaying stuff, then error messages intermingle with `less`'s output and nothing is preserved after `less` exits (because `less` just preserves the terminal as it was before it started and doesn't know anything about the error messages that came in between).

You can see that easily, if you do e.g.

```
grep foo -r /etc | less
```

All the "Permission denied" error messages mix up with `less` output and nothing will be there after you exit. If you do

```
grep foo -r /etc | (sleep 10; less)
```

all (or at least most) of the error messages have been printed to the terminal before `less` gets a chance to display output and you will see the error messages afterwards.

Of course, you don't usually want to wait 10 seconds before you start `less`, but with Linux you can also supply fractional values for the waiting time, and with fast running processes often something as little as `sleep 0.1` is enough to avoid the race condition. (But, of course, if you want or have to be on the *really* safe side use RedGrittyBrick's solution).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of "file descriptors". Usually, a unix application will start with three special file descriptors:

- Standard input
- Standard output
- Standard error

The "pipe" `|` in the shell connects `stdout` from one process with `stdin` of the next.

Errors are - by design - not fed to `stdin` of the next process. They will often not make sense to the next application, and should not be hidden from the user.

If you want to mix the errors into stdout, you can use e.g. `2>&1`, which says essentially "append stderr to stdout". For example

```
find /etc 2>&1 | less
```

should also include error output from inaccessible files.

```
find /etc 2>&1 >/dev/null | less
```

will give you the errors only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your question, as far as I ca tell your desired behavior is the default.

When I use

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
  for (int j=0; j<10; ++j){
    fprintf( (j%2 ? stdout : stderr) , "%d\n" , j);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

to get a simple test,

```
$ ./testredirection | less
```

does just what you ask. That is I see

```
1
3
5
7
9
(END)
```

in `less` and

```
$ ./testredirection | less
0
2
4
6
8
$
```

when I quit `less`

Comment: It's strange but things are not always like this. Try with a script (`echo info ; echo error 1>&2`) and repeat the test: both lines are piped to less.

Comment: @cYrus: That works as expected for me, too. 'Course I tried in on a Mac OS box. Bash 3.2.17, less 394. Maybe something linux specific. In any case RedGrittyBrick's approach should work fine.

Comment: Weird! Debian Squeeze / Bash 4.1.5 / Less 436

Comment: Yeah, I opened a shell of Scientific Linux 5.3 box at work and got the expected behavior with bash 3.0.15 and less 382. Could there be a regression in there?

Comment: I don't know, I think it's just a matter of buffering.

Comment: @cYrus: It occurs to me that the difference is probably the *terminal* we're using, as both my tests were in `xterm`s (version 269) from the XQuartz 2.6.3. Indeed, the Mac OS 10.5 `Terminal.app` gets it "wrong" the first time then "right" subsequently. Huh? I guess that argues in favor of a buffering explanation, but I'm not going to try to figure it out any more.

Comment: The default behavior I'm getting (with no redirection) is that stderr lines get outputted in less but in an ephemeral way: if you scroll them out of view and go back, they're not there (neither are they in the console after less exits).

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with GNU bash versions 5.0.17 and 4.4.20 respectively, Konsole terminal, I get similar behavior to OP and @haelix:

 - When the output is less than 1 screen long, `stderr` is intermingled with stdout in `less` output, and lost after closing `less` or redrawing (`CTRL+L`).
 - When the output is more than 1 screen long, intermingling is a bit out of order, has erroneous `:` symbol in the middle of the screen (which is supposed to be at the bottom to indicate the `less` prompt); `stderr` is lost on scrolling, redrawing, or exiting `less`.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to encounter this problem in one of my Debian 5.0's recently.
for example, ls abc | less
I find that the error message go into less, which against my knowledge.

After some attempts, I found that it is just something related to screen buffers. stderr does NOT go into less actually.
You can use Up or Down arrow keys (or j/k) to demonstrate.