# How can I redirect OS X dtruss output when running with sudo?

Tags: macos, bash, sudo, redirection

I'm running `dtruss` on Mac OS X 10.9. Simple example is:

```
sudo -c ls
```

But I'd like to capture the `dtruss` output into a file. I saw something that suggests that I can do something like:

```
sudo bash -c 'dtruss -c ls >x'
```

but when I do this the output of `dtruss` still goes to the terminal and the list of file from `ls` gets redirected to the file.

How can I redirect the output of `dtruss` to a file?

Comment: dtruss probably writes to `stderr` instead of `stdout` witch is what `>x` captures. This questions explains what to do: [Linux less behavior and stderr](http://superuser.com/questions/366596/linux-less-behavior-and-stderr)

Answer (score 9):

I've been running it like this:

```
sudo dtruss -f -p 12345 2> /tmp/trace.txt
```

- `-f` says to follow child processes.
- `-p` specifies which process ID to trace.
- `12345` is a placeholder for a process ID. You could get that by looking at `top` or `ps -A`.
- `2>` pipes standard error into the output file. For some reason dtruss outputs everything on stderr.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain what this does?  Thanks.

Comment: '-f' says follow child processes, '-p' specifies which process ID to trace, '2>' pipes standard error into the output file. For some reason dtruss outputs everything on stderr.

Comment: Is 12345 a placeholder for the process ID (and where would that come from)?

Comment: It is a placeholder for a process ID. You could get that by looking at `top` or `ps -A`.